# Flutter Widget names showing as widget on build apk. But works well on run

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, dart, widget

I was trying to print the name of an object inside a list using the statement tabs[index].toString(). Where tabs is an array of objects.
I'm seeing the title of the widgets as just "widget" instead of the name on the build apk. But it works well on the instant run from an android studio.  What could be the error? I'm attaching the screenshot and app code below.
[image: This is the build apk]

```
List<Widget> tabs = <Widget>[
  new Shopping(),
  new Fashion(),
  new Food(),
  new Recharge(),
  new Travel(),
  new Hotel(),
  new Lens(),
  new Medicine(),
  new Movie(),
  new Grocery(),
  new BabyProducts(),
  new Furniture(),
  new Print(),
  new Classifieds(),
  new GiftsFlowers()
];

   body: new TabBarView(
      controller: _tabController,
      children: new List<Widget>.generate(tabs.length, (int index) {
        return tabs[index];
      }),
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: new Material(
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      child: new TabBar(
        controller: _tabController,
        labelColor: Colors.white,
        isScrollable: true,
        tabs: new List.generate(tabs.length, (index) {
          return new Tab(
            text: tabs[index].toString(),
          );
        }),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: It is because of this line - `text: tabs[index].toString()`

Comment: but it is showing tab name as intented on running from an android studio.

Comment: did you try with `tabs[index].runTimeType.toString()` ?

Comment: If even this doesn't work, the surest and maybe the ideal way to do this right, is to include a String member variable in each of these Widget classes and use that, instead of relying on `Object.toString()`